# Как найти хардкорные текстовые строки в коде?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

И так писал приложение, но не всегда строки заносил в ресурсы, а теперь когда его дописал надо бы все в ресурсы занести, но искать все строки в коде/layout не очень удобно и долго. Может быть есть какой-то способ, чтобы сразу показал все строки, а мне только добавить их.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сначала запустите инспекцию кода для всего проекта (появится диалоговое окно, что инспектировать): *Analyze -> Inspect Code*

После завершения анализа вы получите список обнаруженных проблем, среди которых будет *Hardcored text* (Секции *Android > Lint > Internalization*).
По двойному клику на каждую запись вы перейдете к тому месту в коде (или разметке), где у вас захардкордленые строки.

[image: scrn]

Далее, перейдя к нужной стоке, слева от нее появится желтая лампочка, кликнув на нее, выберите пункт *Extract String Resource* - инструмент поможет перенести строку в ресурс *string.xml* с возможной интерализацией (переводами на другие языки)

[image: scrn]

Answer (score 6):

Найти такие строки легко: в настройках выставьте для "Hrdcoded text" уровень Error (по умолчанию он warning). И все подобные строки у вас подсветятся красным + при компиляции будет выдавать шибки.

```
 Inspections -> Hrdcoded text -> Severity -> Error
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтобы посмотреть все подобные строки разом запустите `Analyze -> Inspect code`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]