# Android Studio, можно ли как-то разом добавить строковые ресурсы для строк, на которые жалуется студия?

Tags: android-studio

Допустим, в разметке есть `ImageButton`, для нее требует описание `ContentDescription`, когда его добавляешь, то просит эту строку добавить в `strings.xml`, также с текстом на кнопках, текстом в `TextView`, у меня их уже 40+ накопилось. Можно ли как-то разом их все добавить в `strings.xml` или только ручками?

Comment: полностью автоматически не получится, но немного [облегчить можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527049/177345). Вообще это нужно делать при создании каждого виджета, а не когда их накопится 40+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только в ручную, но на работу это не влияет.